# getText() method not showing in dateChooser in java

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, gettext, jdatechooser

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx1n0.jpg) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6MG0.jpg) [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGXSu.jpg)

I want to use the JDateChooser. and i want to get the text inside it. I saw in yt tutorials and asked my friend abt it. He told me that he can use the getText(). idk why i cant use it in mine.

tried using the `getDate().toString().` but the time format is different. The time format that i chose is `yyyy-MM-dd.` But the display date is `Fri Jan 01 01:01:23 PST 9999`

Comment: Read the [API](https://papio.biology.duke.edu/repos/ranker/doc-lib/JCalendar/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html) for the class an use the appropriate method. I would guess you need to use the `setDateFormatString()` to format the Date in the chooser. If you want to format the Date outside of the chooser then you would need to use the `DateFormat` class with the same format string. Don't post images of code. Post the actual code in the format of an [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Try DateFormat instead of toString() directly

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd);
formatter.format(getDate());
```